# Business Data Connectivity Services in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am getting "Business Data Connectivity is configured incorrectly. Administrators, see the server log for more information" error. Any help I really appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a SharePoint 2007 server, it's not going to work - the VS2010 tools are for SharePoint 2010 servers, with the exception of workflows.

Comment: Hi Greg, I am using Sharpoint 2010. I am not sure whether this has  any thing to do with the SQL autontication

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the ULS log or the Event Log? That should provide you some more information.
The ULS log can be found here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I did check the Event log it show me only DAT file. I really don't know how to open that file

Comment: You could also go into Central Administration and view the Properties for this Service Application. This may point you at what is wrong.

You can do this by:
1. Open SharePoint 2010 Central Administration
2. Select Manage service applications under the Application Management section
3. Click to the right of Business Data Connectivity Service to select it (don't click on the actual text)
4. In the ribbon, select Properties

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx Doung I followed your step but I didn't see property in the ribbon.

Comment: When you clicked on Business Data Connectivity Service, did it select the row or did it redirect you to a different page? You should be able to just click on the row (not the text part) and select the row. After you do that the Properties icon in the ribbon will be enabled. In fact, the Properties icon should be there before you select the row... it's just disabled until you select the row.

Comment: That is right I was opening the next page. I am in the right page now and the Database authentication section is empty. Do you think that might be the cause? If so do I have to specify that? Thanks a lot

Comment: I assume you have it set to Windows Authentication, which is the default. You most likely want to leave that, but you should check the Application Pool that is specified, and check the account that the Application Pool is running under in IIS. This is the account that is likely having authentication issues.

Comment: It uses the existing application pool. And configurable section has other user/adminstrator account name. Do I need to change that or create a new application pool? Thanks again

Comment: By default, the Database section uses Windows Authentication and the Application Pool should be set to SharePoint Web Services Default. You can go into IIS and check this Application Pool to see which Identity it is running under. This may identify your problem.

Comment: Doung,


This time I am getting different error "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."


Also if I open it in SharePoint designer 2010 to get more information it says "unhandled exception, Object reference not set to an object".  Any ideas?

Comment: You've lost me now. Are you saying that you are getting the error on the configuration page for the Business Data Connectivity Service? If so, you may need to recreate the service application.

Comment: No. In my SharePoint site when I tried to create external list and use the BDC service model as the data source.